# releasing mediaplayer when calling OnDestroy forces exit when backplayer pressed

Tags: android, media-player, ondestroy

I have an app that plays audio after taking the user through a couple of views. At first all worked fine except when the backbutton is pressed while audio is playing at which point the app closed but the audio carried on. After researching, I put in the OnDestroy method and released the mediaplayer which now stops when the back button is pressed during the audio play.

However now when the back button is pressed during one of the previous views before the mediaplayer is started I get a force close message and the logcat says Unable to Destroy Activity - I assume because there is no mediaplayer for it to release? Does anyone know what is going on?

I have tried an if statement to super.OnDestroy only when media is playing but this has no effect.

Comment: Without seeing any code it's impossible to tell. I'd guess, however, your `MediaPlayer` reference is either `null` or the `MediaPlayer` instance isn't in a 'valid' state for you to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to release your `Mediaplayer` but that you didn't initialize it if the user is not playing a song it makes sense that you're getting an Exception.

As often, verifying if your value is null or not is probably the key. One more thing : don't handle this case in `onDestroy` because it is not guaranteed to be called, prefer `onStop` to it if possible.

Comment: yes I think I am getting a nullpointerexception'. How can I initialize media player before I have started it? Presumably I would have to initialize it directly after the MainActivity is called.

Comment: ok I have managed to initialize it from another thread and it appears to work ok now. Thanks for your help and advice on the the onStop